# Confusing Ninject Scoping behavior of WCF service

Tags: c#, wcf, ninject

It seems no scoping behavior works as expected. I have a very simple WCF service application:

Service.cs:

```
public class Service : IService, IDisposable
{
    public Service()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Service instantiated");
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Service disposed");
    }

    ...
}
```

ConsoleHost.cs:

```
internal static class ConsoleHost
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var kernel = new StandardKernel();

        // this line is changed to produce results below
        kernel.Bind<Service>().ToSelf().InSingletonScope();

        var host = kernel.Get<NinjectServiceHost<Service>>();

        host.Open();
        Console.ReadKey();
        host.Close();
        ((IDisposable) host).Dispose();
    }
}
```

When the service is in Singleton scope these are the logs after 2 requests:

```
Service instantiated // this line is immediately after the app starts
Service disposed     // this is after the first requests finishes
Service instantiated
Service disposed
```

So Ninject instantiates the Service, and keeps it open while it waits for the first request.

When in Request scope this is what happens:

```
Service instantiated
Service instantiated
Service disposed
Service disposed
Service instantiated
Service disposed
Service disposed
```

Ninject still instantiates the service when starting the app, but now it doesn't ever dispose of it, even after the first request finishes. To top it of, it seems to call the Dispose method twice now.

Transient scope behavior is the same as with Request scope, but Dispose is called only once. Is this a bug with Ninject/WCF, or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: I'd suggest you to log the stack trace both at instantiation and disposal so you can see who's calling that

Comment: your setup seems very far from the one described here : https://github.com/ninject/Ninject.Extensions.Wcf/wiki/Configure-wcf-service-library
Have you tried testing with this code ?

Comment: @jbl If I understand correctly, this is used when the service is hosted in another process or in IIS, I'm hosting in a console app. But the base class, `NinjectServiceHost`, is the same in both cases so there shouldn't be any difference. Anyway, I've since switched to SimpleInjector, and it's working as expected in there.